# Calling a instance value in a different method

Tags: c#, methods

I don't know how to access my instance in another method. I have this set of code.

```
Card rorbcard = new Card();
        Deck deck = new Deck();
        deck.Shuffle();
        rorbcard = deck.TakeCard();
        Start0:
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Allright lets play! Red or black?");
        string userValue0 = Console.ReadLine();
        switch (userValue0.ToLower())
        {
            case "red":
                {
                    if (rorbcard.Suit.Equals(Suit.Diamonds))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("{0},\n Correct give 2 drinks",
                          rorbcard.ToString());
                            Thread.Sleep(2000);
                        }
                    else if (rorbcard.Suit.Equals(Suit.Hearts))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0},\n Correct give 2 drinks",
                        rorbcard.ToString());
                        Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0},\n Wrong sucka take 2 drinks",
                        rorbcard.ToString());
                        Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    }
                }
```

I am trying to use that rorbcard.ToString() in another method, but I cant figure out how to reference it. Here is the other method.

```
 public void HighLow()
    {
        //highlow part of the game
        Deck deck = new Deck();
        deck.Shuffle();
        Card highLow = new Card();
        highLow = deck.TakeCard();
    Start1:
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Your Hand:");
        Grid.WriteAt(rorbcard.ToString(), 0, 1);
        Console.WriteLine("\n\nDo you think that the next card will higher,lower,\n or
        equal to the {0}. Enter high, low, or equal\n", rorbcard);
        string uservalue1 = Console.ReadLine();
        switch (uservalue1.ToLower())
        {
            case "high":

                if (highLow.CardNumber > rorbcard.CardNumber)  <-----Issue
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0},\n Correct give 4 drinks",
                    highLow.ToString());
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0},\n Wrong  drink 4\n", highLow.ToString());
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                }
```

Thanks for your time in looking into this. I am stuck and have been for a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed to do was place my instances outside the methods and inside my class. Duh

Comment: Since you basically followed Nikhil's advice (you created private variables), you should really consider marking his answer as the accepted one instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can do either

a. Pass as parameter to `HighLow()` like

```
public void HighLow(string rorbcard)
```

b. Create a class level variable. Assign value to it and use that value in `HighLow()` like

```
class MyClass
{
    private string rorbCardClassLevel;

    private void MyrorbCardMethod
    {
        //Other code lines.

        //Inside case statement
        rorbCardClassLevel = rorbcard.ToString();
    }

    private void HighLow()
    {
        //Use rorbCardClassLevel here.            
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I create a class level variable? How would I assign the value of rorbcard = deck.TakeCard();?

Comment: If I do that when I use rorbCardClassLevel in the HighLow() method it will not have any of the functionality of rorbCard. Like I cant call the .CardNumber or the .Suit
On a side note thanks for helping me